# How can I return an RxJava Observable which is guaranteed not to throw OnErrorNotImplementedException?

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to create a pattern in my application where all `Observable<T>` objects that are returned have some default error handling, meaning that the subscribers may use the `.subscribe(onNext)` overload without fear of the application crashing. (Normally you'd have to use `.subscribe(onNext, onError)`). Is there any way to acheive this?

I've tried attaching to the Observable by using `onErrorReturn`, `doOnError` and `onErrorResumeNext` - without any of them helping my case. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I still get `rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException` if an error occurs within the Observable.

Edit 1: This is example of an Observable that emits an error, which I want to handle in some middle layer:

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Somebody set up us the bomb"));
});
```

Edit 2: I've tried this code to handle the error on behalf of the consumer, but I still get `OnErrorNotImplementedException`:

```
// obs is set by the method illustrated in edit 1
obs = obs.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
    System.out.println("This error is handled by onErrorResumeNext");
    return null;
});
obs = obs.doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("A second attempt at handling it"));
// Consumer code:
obs.subscribe(
    s -> System.out.println("got: " + s)
);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of `OnErrorNotImplementedException`? The stack track of `OnErrorNotImplementedException` should contain the real exception in your codes.

Comment: The real exception is irrelevant in this case. What's relevant is that `subscriber.onError` is called internally by the Observable, and the end subscriber should not need to define a method to handle that error. I.e. a middle layer should take care of it.

Comment: See edit for an example of such an observable

Comment: How do you use `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResumeNext `? It should catch the error except you throws some error in `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResumeNext `.

Comment: See my edit 2.  `onErrorReturn` would work, but I really don't want the consumer to receive *any* event if an error occurs. only if it completes successfully

Comment: onErrorResumeNext expects an Observable, but you return null.

Comment: See my answer, found "Observable.empty" to be the key, after googling some. Thanks for putting me on the right track :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work - the key was to `return Observable.empty();`

```
private <T> Observable<T> attachErrorHandler(Observable<T> obs) {
    return obs.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
        System.out.println("Handling error by printint to console: " + throwable);
        return Observable.empty();
    });
}

// Use like this:
Observable<String> unsafeObs = getErrorProducingObservable(); 
Observable<String> safeObservable = attachErrorHandler(unsafeObs);
// This call will now never cause OnErrorNotImplementedException
safeObservable.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Result: " + s));
```